# Angular 6 test httpclient post method

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine, angular6

How would I go about testing this? The http methods and the part inside the subscribe method. I would extract some of the logic into a service but I don't have that choice. Am using angular 6 which is using karma annd jasmine.

```
export class ProviderSubTypeAddEditComponent implements OnInit {
    onSubmit() {
          if (!this.isedit) {
            this.httpClient.post(`${e.serverURL}${this.url}`,
              {
                name: this.form.get('providerTypeLabel').value,
                provider_type: this.form.get('selectedOption').value,
              })
              .subscribe(
                  data => {
                    this.saveaction.emit(true);
                    this.snotifyService.async('Kindly wait ...', this.successAction).eventEmitter.subscribe(d =>{
                      if(d === 'hidden'){
                          if (this.hasback){
                            this.router.navigateByUrl('/provider_sub_types/list');
                        }
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  error => {
                    this.snotifyService.error("An Error Occured. Kindly contact support.")
                  },
              );
          } else {
            // patch action
            this.httpClient.patch(`${e.serverURL}${this.url}${this.providerid}/`,
              {
                name: this.form.get('providerTypeLabel').value,
                provider_type: this.form.get('selectedOption').value,
              })
              .subscribe(
                  data => {
                      this.patchaction.emit(true);
                      this.snotifyService.success("Provider subtype edited successfully.")
                  },
                  error => {
                    this.snotifyService.error("An Error Occured. Kindly contact support.")
                  },
              );
          }

        }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Testing this method will be a nightmare. Forget about it unless you split it into smaller methods and clean up your `subscribe()` methods. These lines: `this.saveaction.emit(true);
                    this.snotifyService.async('Kindly wait ...', this.successAction).eventEmitter.subscribe(d =>{` are a really bad practice - you have event emitter, stream and subscribe inside another subscribe. It's a big no no when using RxJS. Why can't you have http methods in the service?